# SAS Data Step if statement not working

Tags: sas

With the below code the email always gets sent. 1 obviously does not equal 0, but yet it still runs. I have tried removing the do part but still get the same issue.

```
data _null_;
set TestTable;
if 1 = 0 then do;
    file sendit email
    to=("email@gmail.com")
    subject="Some Subject Line";
end;    
run;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do by comparing 1 to 0, but many languages wouldn't handle comparing two literal constants like that.

Comment: I was using it to test, because no matter what I put in there it always sends the email

Comment: @TriskalJM SAS is fine with that construct.  (I would use the shorter `if 0`, but `if 1 = 0` works fine.)

Comment: @Joe Michael's problem remains, then. And what a strange language ;)

Comment: @TriskalJM Well, I would consider it strange the other way really... SAS is a 4GL, though, so it's not low-level optimized like C or even Java.  Comparing 1 to 0 is a legal boolean comparison, albeit a strange one.  SAS will occasionally tell you things like `**an obviously false statement**`, though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the `file` statement is considered an executable statement (and thus should not be executed when behind a false `if` statement), that is not really entirely true.  SAS sees the `file` statement during compilation, and knows that it needs to create a file to write to - and thus, it's somewhat compile-time.  That's what is happening here - SAS creates the file (in this case, the email) as a result of the compiler's activity, then doesn't actually populate it with anything, but still has an email at the end of the day.

The same thing happens with any other file - like so:

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  if 0 then do;
      file "c:\temp\test_non_zero.txt";
      put name $;
  end;
run;
```

A blank file is created by that code.

If you need to conditionally send emails, I would recommend wrapping your email code in a macro, and then calling that macro using `call execute` or similar from the dataset.  Like so:

```
%macro write_email(parameters);
data _null_;
  file sendit email
  to=("email@gmail.com")
  subject="Some Subject Line";
run;
%mend write_email;

data _null_;
  set TestTable;
  if 0 then do;
     call execute('%write_email(parameters)');
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use email directives to abort the message.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002058232.htm

```
data _null_;
  file sendit email to=("email@gmail.com") subject="Some Subject Line";
  if nobs=0 then put '!EM_ABORT!';
  set TestTable nobs=nobs;
  ....
run;
```